# Calculating probability of finding collisions in an invertible hash function

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Assuming we have an invertible hash function *H* that takes inputs of size **2n** and outputs hashes of size **n**, I use the following algorithm to find collisions:

1. Choose a random *M* as input.
2. Compute its hash E = H(M)
3. Compute the inverse of the hash M' = H<sup>-1</sup>(E)
4. Collision if M != M', fail otherwise.

I'm trying to calculate the probability that the algorithm finds a collision. We have **2<sup>2n</sup>** possible inputs, and **2<sup>n</sup>** possible outputs. This means that on average we have `22n / 2n = 2n` preimages for every output hash. The probability of the algorithm finding a collision is then the probability of randomly choosing two unique values out of the hash's preimages (2<sup>n</sup>). So: `(2n - 1) / 2n`.

At least this is my solution. From the notes I have, the TA solved it something like this:

`x = 22n/2n = 2n/n = 2
Probability(M == M') = 1/x = 1/2
Probability(M != M') = 1 - 1/x = 1/2`

Am I wrong? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Well, it is certainly true that  2^2n/2^n=2^n.

Comment: I would've interpreted this as you did, but they might mean "n possible output values" rather than "set of output values is {0,1}$^n$", and similarly for the inputs. ​ ​ ​ In any case, ​ $2^{2\cdot n}/\hspace{.02 in}2^n = 2^n > 2^1 = 2 = 2n/n$ ​ is true for all real numbers $n$ that are greater than $1$. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: A function that takes inputs of size $2n$ and outputs hashes of size $n$ can't be invertible, unless $n=0$, by a counting argument. It might be computationally possible to find a preimage, but then it's not a cryptographically secure hash, and I don't see we can reason on the probability of finding collision. Baring voiced disagreement on this reasoning, or clarification, I plan to close the question as unclear [update: done].

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of the meaning of size $2n$ if size is number of possible values, than indeed each test has probability $1/2$ to find a collision.

If the size is bit length than each test has probability $1-1/{2^n}$ of finding a collision as you wrote.

Also note these calculations are lower bounds for collision finding probability. Some functions may collide much more. Alternatively these are the probabilities for an idealized hash function.